# Using Multiple Process templates in single VSTS instance

Tags: templates, process, azure-devops

Is it possible to use multiple templates in a single instance of VSTS?

I have 20+ teams using VSTS that are doing different kinds of work. Given that, some teams would like to use the out of the box Scrum Template and some of the teams would like to use the Agile template. Can this be done or am I limited to one template per VSTS Node?

Follow on Question, if I am limited to a single temple, can I control what fields are visible in Stories & Tasks on a team by team basis?

Example -- I create a custom field that is visible in one teams task but it is not visible in a different teams tasks.

Thanks

Comment: Are these teams contained in the same Team Project, or are they in different Team Projects?

Comment: The goal is to have all teams in a single instance of VSTS so that we can split work across teams but still have a unified report that can capture all relevant data to the Epic or Feature.  I guess I am unclear if we are using Instance and Team Project for the same thing.  There will be a single top level, that will branch two or three levels down to the teams actually doing the work.  My question is can the delivery teams in this scenario use different process templates.

Comment: A "team project" is a specific term that is used throughout VSTS. "Instance" isn't, and I'm not sure if you're calling a "team project" an "instance", or if you're referring to something else, like the VSTS account. Look up the term "team project" as it relates to VSTS and see if we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Jefe', Did you resolve this issue in your side? We could create different projects under different work item process using the single VSTS accout:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav, We could also control the visit permission for different project:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/add-team-members-vs?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cprevious-nav, is it the solution you want to get?

Comment: Daniel Mann, I am sorry for the imprecise language.  I was using the term Instance to describe a single installation of VSTS.  My understanding is that this could support multiple projects.  If this is true my questions are as follows;  1) can you roll up reporting across projects?  2) can a single project support two teams that that want to use two different task templates because of the kind of work they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible to use multiple process templates.
you can create a project for each team, in each project you can define another process template.

- Choose the  VSTS icon to open the Projects page, and then choose Create Project.

[image: Create Project]

- Fill out the form provided. Provide a name for your new project, select its initial source control type, **select a process**, and choose with whom to share the project.

[image]

Comment: I know I can create multiple projects, that was not my question.  My question was concerned with tracking work across projects. Can I have reporting on an Epic in one project that has features and stories in other projects?

Answer (score 0):

We have been asking the same question in the project that I am working on - we have multiple teams, who are wanting to use multiple templates and have different sized iterations.

The solution that we have utilized is to use multiple projects for each team, rather than a single project, but then use a data visualization tool, such as Power BI, to complete the reporting.

Power BI has Data Connectors that allow direct connections to your VSTS instance, allowing you to gain input from multiple projects. Once the connections have been made, you can append and merge queries to provide a singular query that pulls data from multiple projects.

Microsoft have documented connecting your vsts instance to Power BI - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=vsts

The projects themselves can also be linked, features in one project can have child processes within a different project meaning each project is not in a complete silo.